# Clementine to play song when selected in Explorer

Tags: windows-8

Having recently upgraded to Windows 8, I'm doing a general "upgrade" of the programs I use, starting with a better media player. Clementine was recommended to me by a friend, and so far it seems nice.

One question, though, even though I've associated .mp3 files with Clementine, double-clicking them just adds them to the playlist. I want it to replace the playlist with the chosen file.

I have tried hopping into `regedit.exe` and finding the shell command, changing it to this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Clementine\clementine.exe" -l "%L" -p
```

The intention here is to use the `-l` option to replace the playlist (this works), then the `-p` option to begin playing the new playlist (this does not)

What am I doing wrong here? Or, for fear of being an X/Y problem, how do I associate media files with Clementine in a quick and easy way?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should have 2 registry keys associated with opening MP3's in Clementine:

```
Path: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Clementine music player.AssocFile.MP3\shell\open\command
Key: @="<path>\<to>\<Clementine>\clementine.exe" "%1"
Corrected key: @="<path>\<to>\<Clementine>\clementine.exe" -l "%1" -p
```

and...

```
Path: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Clementine music player.AssocFile.MP3\shell\play\command
Key: @="<path>\<to>\<Clementine>\clementine.exe" "%L"
Corrected key: @="<path>\<to>\<Clementine>\clementine.exe" -l "%L" -p
```

Correcting this worked for me. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: That's basically what I did :p It works for the first one, but after that it will just restart the current playlist (even though the playlist has been overwritten by the `-l` file)

Comment: Hmm weird. I actually have your problem the first time when I open a MP3 file before Clementine is running. When the first song starts playing I can just double click a MP3 file and it clear the playlist and starts playing. I'll see if I can find a solution for us both...

Comment: I first tested it on Windows 7 x64 and now I tested it on Windows 8.1 x64 as well and the above solution works as long as Clementine is already running. If Clementine isn't running, then the problem occurs to me too. My guess is that there is a faulty logic in the code at startup, which you can report on the GitHub page of Clementine.